# Linked List Operations

Tags: python

Hello I need help trying to figure out these three functions. I am very new to python.

Assignment:

- createList(srcSeq) - creates a linked list from the values
  contained in the srcSeq sequence structure and returns the head
  reference of the new linked list. The values will be added one at a
  time by prepending them to the linked list. myValues = [5, 12, 82,
  32, 20] myList = createList(myValues)
- size(theList) - given the
  head reference (theList), returns the number of   elements in the
  linked list.
- printList(theList) - given the head reference
  (theList), prints the values in the linked list from front to back
  all on one line with the values separated by commas.
- valueAt(theList, index) - returns the value contained in the node at 
  the given index position where the first value is at position 0, the 
  second at position 1 and so on. If index is out of range, return
  None.
- append(theList, value) - appends a new value to the end of
  the linked list. Assume the list contains at least one node.
- concat(listA, listB) - joins or concatenates two linked lists by
  linking the last node of listA to the first node of listB.
- split(theList) - given the head reference (theList), splits the
  linked list in half to create two smaller linked lists. The head
  reference of the linked list created from the second half of the list
  is returned. Assume the list contains at least one node. If there is 
  an odd number of nodes in the linked list, the extra node can be
  placed in either of the two new lists.

For the append, concat, do I simply just do. I do not know how to do the split method:

```
  def append (theList, value):
      current = self.head
      while current.self.next != None:
          current = self.next
      current.newnode

  def concat(listA, listB):
      if listA.tail == None:
          listA.head = listB.head
      else:
          listA.tail.next = listB.head
      elif listB.head != None:
          listA.tail = listB.tail
```

My Entire Code:

```
  def createList( self ):
      self.head = None
      temp = ListNode( value )
      self.next = newnext
      temp.self.next(self.head)
      self.head = temp
      return self.head

  def size( theList ):
      current = self.head
      count = 0
      while current != None:
          count = count + 1
          current = current.self.next

      return count

  def printList( theList ):
      node = self.head
      while node:
          print self.value
          node = self.next

  def valueAt( theList, index ):
      current = head
      count = 0
      while current != None:
          if count == index:
              return current

  def append( theList, value ):
      current = self.head
      while current.self.next != None:
          current = self.next
      current.newnode


  def concat( listA, listB ):
      if listA.tail == None:
          listA.head = listB.head
      else:
          listA.tail.next = listB.head
      elif listB.head != None:
          listA.tail = listB.tail


  def split( theList ):
      pass
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there any concrete thing you're having problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you problem is under-specified. but with what we have :

### Splitting a singly linked list:

```
def split( head ):
    middle = head
    current = head
    index = 0
    while current.next != None:
        if index % 2:
            middle = middle.next
        current = current.next
        index += 1
    result = middle.next
    middle.next = None
    return result
```

But to be honest, there is a lot more wrong with what you have so far.

### If those lists were Python lists the solution would be really simple:

```
def split(a):
    return a[:len(a)/2], a[len(a)/2:]
```

#### And now some explanation :) :

The function returns a *tuple* of two lists, where each list is one half of the supplied list **a**.
What I use above is called [slicing](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) and you can think of  the *colon* character as of the word *until*. You can supply two _arguments **beginning** and **end** separated by that **semicolon**.

### Example time!

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a[:2]    == [1,2]
a[2:]    == [3,4,5]
a[1:3]   == [2,3,4]
a[2,-2]  == [3]
a[-3,-2] == [3,4]
```

Isn't slicing great? And it comes for free! One extra trick, if you want to make a copy of a list you can do that with slicing too!

```
b = a[:]
```

#### Boom, done! :)

There is more to slicing, you can have two colons, but that's a story for another time.

*PS:*
Out of curiosity I did your homework :)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(self.data)


def create_list(iterable):
    next_node = current_node = None
    for item in iterable:
        current_node = Node(item)
        current_node.next = next_node
        next_node = current_node
    return current_node


def size(head):
    count = 0
    while head:
        head = head.next
        count += 1
    return count


def print_list(head):
    while head:
        print(head, end="")
        if head.next:
            print(" > ", end="")
        head = head.next
    print(flush=True)
    pass


def value_at(head, index):
    while (head):
        if index < 1:
            return head
        index -= 1
        head = head.next
    return None


def append(head, value):
    while head:
        if not head.next:
            head.next = Node(value)
            return
        head = head.next


def concat(headA, headB):
    while headA:
        if not headA.next:
            headA.next = headB
            return
        headA = headA.next


def split(head):
    center = head
    index = 0
    while head:
        if index % 2:
            center = center.next
        head = head.next
        index += 1
    headB = center.next
    center.next = None
    return headB


def main():
    a = create_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    print("Print list::")
    print_list(a)
    print("\nSize:")
    print(size(a))
    print("\nValue at:")
    print("a[-1]: %d" % value_at(a, -1).data)
    print("a[0]: %d" % value_at(a, 0).data)
    print("a[1]: %d" % value_at(a, 1).data)
    print("a[5]: %d" % value_at(a, 5).data)
    print("a[8]: %d" % value_at(a, 8).data)
    # print("value @ 9 %d"% value_at(my_head,9).data)
    print("\nAppend (10):")
    print_list(a)
    append(a, 10)
    print_list(a)
    print("\nConcat a, b:")
    print_list(a)
    b = create_list([11, 12, 13])
    print_list(b)
    concat(a, b)
    print_list(a)
    print("\nSplit:")
    print_list(a)
    print("..into..")
    b = split(a)
    print_list(a)
    print("Size a: %d" % size(a))
    print_list(b)
    print("Size b: %d" % size(b))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That is for Python lists. The OP wants one for linked lists.

Comment: You're right, I added a solution for linked list or at least the type of linked list OP is trying to implement. But there is way more wrong with this question.

Comment: I fixed all those other issues too :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I am very new to python and your explanation was great help.For the split method, which one is for linked lists, the one you completed first or the one where you attempted my assignment? I am confused on whether you did my assignment using a singly linked list? Just trying to understand :)

Comment: I did the assignment with a singly linked list.  
See the class **Node**? That is one item in your singly linked list, adn as you can see all it holds is the _data_ and _next_. Data holds .. well the data and next points at the next Node in this singly linked list.  
Think of it this way, what is a chain but a sequence of chain links? Each chain link only knows about the  next one (and the previous one, but not in you assignment ;) hence the _singly_ linked list).  
Doubly linked list (chain) would know about the previous chain link too, there would also be _previous_ as well as _next_.

Comment: Expect _doubly linked list_ in the next assignment. Also, please mark answers that solve your question with that check. And upvotes are appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much!I I understand what you are saying now. Just did not know whether to look at your split method at the top or your split method within the assignment.